# Calculate size of record column

Tags: sql, database, data-structures

If i have a table like this then insert it 16 digit for each column except the PK

```
CREATE TABLE x 
(
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    col1 BIGINT,
    col2 CHAR(16)
) Engine=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO x 
VALUES (1234567890123456, '1234567890123456');
```

Then the size of col1 it will stored 8 byte, and the size of col2 it will stored 16 byte.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Why do you want to know? How would you calculate indexes with `INCLUDE` clauses with copies of your table's data?

Comment: Because i'm worry that my understanding is wrong, so i need to confrm it in order to create more efficient in size of record.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL database has not a function for calculating the size of columns, but you can do this manually by writing your own function. Now I will tell you how to do it. Firstly you can get data types of columns by this query:

```
select 
    c.COLUMN_NAME, 
    c.DATA_TYPE, 
    c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH 
from information_schema.`COLUMNS` c 
where c.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test' and c.TABLE_NAME = 'test_table';
```

You will get data

```
id      bigint      null
col1    bigint      null
col2    char        31
col3    varchar     58
```

So, you can write your own function that is `function get_size_column(column_name varchar)` input parameter. Inside the function, you must control data types of the column, for example `if datatype = bigint then size = 8`, such datatypes as int, smallint, bigint are static sizes. `If datatype = varchar or char` you must use `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` field. I wrote this for examples, but you have to write if conditions for all types. I must also say that there are many tutorials about MySQL data types and store sizes. After all this process you can use your function in the select statements of your queries.